# BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am hosted in Azure.

i am facing the exception message:

> BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

That is a kind of wired message. It does not help at all.

Stacktrace

> System.InvalidOperationException:    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenTdsConnection
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync
>   (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand+d__17.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

Searched the internet. Found nothing. Thats why i am posting it here.